# Undefine symbols for architecture x86_64 using FFTW

Tags: c, fftw

```
Ceeloss-MacBook-Pro:desktop ceelos$ gcc -o prog -I/usr/local/include test.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fftw_destroy_plan", referenced from:
      _main in test-IBqBdS.o
  "_fftw_execute", referenced from:
      _main in test-IBqBdS.o
  "_fftw_plan_dft_1d", referenced from:
      _main in test-IBqBdS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Ceeloss-MacBook-Pro:desktop ceelos$
```

What's this telling me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's telling you that you forgot to use `-L` and `-l` to tell gcc where the FFTW libraries are and what they're called.

Comment: sorry, I'm really new to this. How exactly would I specify this? My library is under /usr/local/lib

Comment: `-L` takes the library location, and `-l` takes the library filename minus the "lib" and the extension. `-L/usr/local/lib -lfftwwhatever`

Comment: hmm, I keep getting "ld: library not found for -libfftw3.la
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" strange, i'm staring at the file there right now.

Comment: Please read my comment again. I believe that you have missed a couple of things.

Comment: Sorry for having a hard time with this. I entered "gcc -o prog -I/usr/local/include test.c -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3f.la" and it gave me this error.

Comment: Try `-lfftw3f` instead. But you may need to reorder the options.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and reordering, still doesn't find the library. Weird.

Comment: What is the .dylib file called?

Comment: I don't have one. the make install didn't create one nor did it come with the zip file. Unless I was supposed to create one myself.

Comment: yes, two, a regular one and one for floats. libfftw3.a and libfftw3f.a

Comment: That's really strange. If you're passing both arguments and it still can't find the library then I don't know what's going on.

Comment: It's fine, I'll see what I figure. Thanks for all your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I was able to add the .dylibs.